# How to make PHP to redirect a link which is generated from a python function that runs a aws service

Tags: php, python, aws-sdk

I am using aws booto3 and python to generate a quicksite link. Now I want to redirect to that link when a html button is clicked. I am using php and html in front end .. I am also running the code on xamp apachee server.

This is my python code:

```
import boto3
def linker():    
    client = boto3.client('quicksight', aws_access_key_id='   ',aws_secret_access_key='abc', region_name='us-east-2')
p= client.get_dashboard_embed_url(AwsAccountId="123", DashboardId="7d5163cf-801c-6666-ba2d-231d3b2ba1b5", IdentityType="IAM", SessionLifetimeInMinutes=100, ResetDisabled=True, UndoRedoDisabled=True)
return p['EmbedUrl']
```

This is redirect.php:

```
<?php
    $result = exec( "python abc.py" );

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){  
       header("Location: $result");
    }

 ?>
```

This is the html file

```
<form action=redirect.php; ?> id="#form" method="post" name="#form">
<input id='btn' name="submit" type='submit' value='Submit'>
<?php include "redirect.php"; ?>
```